# Expiration of controller action from Sweeper does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, sweeper

Having a controller handling rendering of large XML feeds

```
module Spree
  class FeedsController < Spree::StoreController
    ...

    caches_action :products_out
    cache_sweeper FeedSweeper

    # XML feed in format of `xxxxxxx.com'
    def products_out
      @products = Product.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml
      end
    end
end
```

Bellow is the corresponding sweeper's sublass:

```
module Spree
  class FeedSweeper< ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
    observe Product

    def after_update(product)
      # cache_configured? is nil, @controller is nil here, why ?
      expire_action(:controller => :feeds,
                    :action     => :products_out,
                    :format     => :xml)
    end
end
```

Above `Spree::FeedSweeper` **is** called when `Spree::Product` gets updated, however it seems `expire_action` silently dies and cache won't get invalidated.

Can somebody explain the issue ? Even better suggest some solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which Rails version are you using? `expire_action` seems to be [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Caching/Actions/expire_action) after Rails 3.2.14.

Maybe you can try to find out the key then directly clear it with `Rails.cache.delete(key)`.

Comment: I do use Rails 3.2.17. Is it just deprecated but still working ? I cann't see any error in logs.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid such hacks as manual deletion of cache files. As I can see, `caches_action` generates a hash value and prepends to key name.